# JTable incremental cell fill

Tags: java, swing, background, jtable, cell

How can I fill a JTable Cell incrementally, based on its value. Exactly like a progress bar would do.

Note:
I do not want to use JProgress Bar!
I want to know if there is a way to do it straight in the cell painting renderer

Comment: There's lots of ways to do it.  The value of the cell needs to be the marker, the rest is trivial paint code

Comment: I know that much already I think... The issue is that I need to know the "trivial paint code", and where it put it.  @override paint?  Sorry Im really new to Java and JTable.  So a little example would be appreiciated.

Comment: Well, the responsibility for rendering a cell comes down to `TableCellRenderer` so presumably that would be a place to start ;)

Comment: I am aware of that also already.  As I have custom backgrounds based on the value in the cell.  Now I just want to do a histogram style fill instead of just a striaght fill.  How can I do that?  I dont know how to "paint" in java.  Im just using the setBackground method to set a color.  How can I paint the cell manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the responsibility for the rendering of a cell comes down to `TableCellRenderer`, have a look at [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer), [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

The rest comes down to simply custom painting, have a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details

[image: Progress]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(1, 1);
            model.setValueAt(0, 0, 0);
            JTable table = new JTable(model);
            table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new ProgressTableCellRenderer());
            add(new JScrollPane(table));

            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    Integer value = (Integer)table.getValueAt(0, 0);
                    value++;
                    if (value > 100) {
                        value = 100;
                        ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                    System.out.println(value);
                    table.setValueAt(value, 0, 0);
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

    }

    public class ProgressTableCellRenderer extends JPanel implements TableCellRenderer {

        private int progressValue;

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            if (value instanceof Integer) {
                progressValue = (Integer)value;
            }
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(UIManager.getColor("List.selectionBackground"));
            int x = (int) (getWidth() * (progressValue / 100d));
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, x, getHeight());
            g2d.dispose();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to lead a Java noob!!  Im still not sure if I like Java at all.  Its extremely frustrating lol

Comment: Question: that division by 100d.  How do I fill in my own variable there and have it work??  because I want to take the highest value I have and calculate all others based off that max value.  But when I put in the maxVolume variable there, the cell doesnt paint.

Comment: Normalise your values so that are between 0-1 (or 0-100 which ever is easier), this will make it easier to allow the renderer to do it's job